# How to turn the turtle toward its move direction?

Tags: turtle-graphics

In [Pencil code](http://pencilcode.net/), how to turn the turtle toward its move direction or toward a x,y point (relative to home)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `turnto`:

```
help turnto
turnto(degrees) Turn to a direction. North is 0, East is 90: turnto 270
turnto(x, y) Turn to graphing coordinates: turnto 50, 100
turnto(obj) Turn to page coordinates or an object on the page: turnto lastmousemove
```

Is this what you need?